# Docker Django Postgres FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I am dockerizing my Django app. My configs are the following:

**csgo.env**

```
POSTGRES_NAME='postgres'
POSTGRES_USER='postgres'
POSTGRES_PASSWORD='postgres'
POSTGRES_HOST='postgres_db'
POSTGRES_PORT='5432'
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_NAME', 'postgres'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST', 'postgres_db'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT', '5432'),
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - csgo.env
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db

  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    env_file:
      - csgo.env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME='postgres'
      - POSTGRES_USER='postgres'
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD='postgres'
      - POSTGRES_HOST='postgres_db'
      - POSTGRES_PORT='5432'
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get the typical auth error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"` and I am really stressed of it. I have been looking for a typo a day long and haven't figured it out. Please help me to find the missing piece of code or the typo!

Note:
I know that this kind of questions are overflowed on the Internet. My post is about finding a typo or a mechanical mistake by me. Thanks for understanding and not assigning the post as a duplicate one!

Comment: Guys please help!

Comment: What error does the database report in its log file (or on the console, assuming your docker-compose echos logs to  the same way mine does.)

Comment: Okey, let me show you. You know I just really really sure I have missed something in my configs, but when I look at my files I can't figure out what is not right there...

Comment: ```2022-09-12 15:40:29.938 UTC [32] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2022-09-12 15:40:29.938 UTC [32] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
        Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"```

Comment: @jjanes, could you please help him?

Comment: If the database had already been initialized once with a different user name, it won't be re-initialized with the new user name.  Try removing the container and restarting it from scratch.

Comment: @jjanes, actually, it won't work. I have tried a lot that. The same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

you should set database name in your environment variables:

```
POSTGRES_DB='postgres'
```

Comment: I wonder what is POSTGRES_NAME then?

Comment: No, it didn't work